# Add support for "match against" to hibernate with MetadataBuilderContributor

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, mariadb

I need the full text search power of mysql/mariaDB in my project. The function `MATCH (col1,col2,...) AGAINST (expr [search_modifier])` is not standard.

I did this in the past :

```
package com.ictcg.mariadbwithmatch;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.QueryException;
import org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.Mapping;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;
import org.hibernate.type.Type;

public class MariaDBWithMatchDialect extends MariaDB53Dialect {

    public MariaDBWithMatchDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("match",
                //new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.DOUBLE, "match(?1) against  (?2 in boolean mode)")
                new MatchFunctionTemplate()
                );
    }

    public static class MatchFunctionTemplate implements SQLFunction {
        public MatchFunctionTemplate() {
        }

        @Override
        public String render(Type argumentType, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") List args, SessionFactoryImplementor factory) {
            String template="match(?1";
            int i=2;
            for(;i<args.size();i++)
                template+=",?"+i;
            template+=") against  (?"+i+" in boolean mode)";
            return new TemplateRenderer( template ).render(args, factory);
        }

        @Override
        public Type getReturnType(Type argumentType, Mapping mapping) throws QueryException {
            return StandardBasicTypes.DOUBLE;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasArguments() {
            return true;//renderer.getAnticipatedNumberOfArguments() > 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasParenthesesIfNoArguments() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MATCH(col,col,... ) AGAINST ( ? in boolean mode)";
        }
    }
}
```

It was working but was linked with MariaDB Driver, which is not amazing.

Version 3.0.0 of Spring Boot upgraded Hibernate, it is now necessary to use `MetadataBuilderContributor`.

Does anyone have a sample to fill the following code?

```
metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction("match", new SqmFunctionDescriptor() {
    
    @Override
    public ArgumentsValidator getArgumentsValidator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    
    @Override
    public <T> SelfRenderingSqmFunction<T> generateSqmExpression(List<? extends SqmTypedNode<?>> arguments,
            ReturnableType<T> impliedResultType, QueryEngine queryEngine, TypeConfiguration typeConfiguration) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new SelfRenderingSqmFunction()
        return null;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `FunctionContributor` and register the function there like e.g.

```
functionContributions.getFunctionRegistry().register(
    "match",
    new AbstractSqmSelfRenderingFunctionDescriptor( 
        "match", 
        null, 
        StandardFunctionReturnTypeResolvers.invariant(
            functionContributions.getTypeConfiguration().getBasicTypeRegistry().resolve( StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN )
        ),
        null
    ) {

        @Override
        public void render(
                SqlAppender sqlAppender,
                List<? extends SqlAstNode> sqlAstArguments,
                SqlAstTranslator<?> walker) {
            sqlAppender.append("match");
            char separator = '(';
            for (int i = 0; i < sqlAstArguments.size() - 1; i++) {
                sqlAppender.append(separator);
                separator = ',';
                sqlAstArguments.get(i).accept(walker);
            }
            sqlAppender.append(") against (");
            sqlAstArguments.get(sqlAstArguments.size() - 1).accept(walker);
            sqlAppender.append("in boolean mode)");
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: How can I access to `functionContributions` so?

Comment: You create a `FunctionContributor` implementation which is a Java `ServiceLoader` contract.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.

Here is how I did :

Adding

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor=com.ictcg.mariadbwithmatch.MariaDBMatchFunction
```

to application.properties

And this is the class :

```
package com.ictcg.mariadbwithmatch;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataBuilder;
import org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataBuilderContributor;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.query.sqm.function.AbstractSqmSelfRenderingFunctionDescriptor;
import org.hibernate.query.sqm.produce.function.StandardFunctionReturnTypeResolvers;
import org.hibernate.sql.ast.SqlAstTranslator;
import org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.SqlAppender;
import org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.SqlAstNode;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;
import org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration;

public class MariaDBMatchFunction implements MetadataBuilderContributor {

    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        TypeConfiguration typeConfiguration = new TypeConfiguration();
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction("match",
                new AbstractSqmSelfRenderingFunctionDescriptor("match", null, StandardFunctionReturnTypeResolvers
                        .invariant(typeConfiguration.getBasicTypeRegistry().resolve(StandardBasicTypes.DOUBLE)), null) {
                    @Override
                    public void render(SqlAppender sqlAppender, List<? extends SqlAstNode> sqlAstArguments,
                            SqlAstTranslator<?> walker) {
                        sqlAppender.append("match");
                        char separator = '(';
                        for (int i = 0; i < sqlAstArguments.size() - 1; i++) {
                            sqlAppender.append(separator);
                            separator = ',';
                            sqlAstArguments.get(i).accept(walker);
                        }
                        sqlAppender.append(") against (");
                        sqlAstArguments.get(sqlAstArguments.size() - 1).accept(walker);
                        sqlAppender.append("in boolean mode)");
                    }
                });

}
```

I'm not sure the use of TypeConfiguration typeConfiguration = new TypeConfiguration(); is the best.

Comment: `MetadataBuilderContributor` is deprecated as of 6.0. So `FunctionContributor` is the new way to go.